# Find a minimum spanning tree in different sets

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

Here I have two connected undirected graphs
 `G1 = [V ; E1] and G2 =[V ; E2]` on the same set of vertices V . And assume edges in E1 and E2 have different colors.

Let w(e) be the weight of edge `e ∈ E1 ∪ E2`.

I want to find a minimum weight spanning tree (MSF) among those spanning trees which have at least one edge in each set E1 and E2. In this condition, How to find a proper algorithm for this? I got stuck here a whole night.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two edges *e1 ∈ E1*, *e2 ∈ E2*. They connect between 2 and 4 different vertices in *V*. If they connect 3 or 4 vertices, suppose you first contract the vertices which *e1* connects (same as each step in [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm)), then the ones which *e2* connects, and then run any [minimum spanning tree algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) on the resulting graph. Then the result is the MST containing *e1* and *e2*.

It follows that you can find the total MST by looping over all *e1 ∈ E1*, *e2 ∈ E2* (which don't connect exactly the same two vertices), and finding the lightest solution. The proof of correctness can be easily modified from that of [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm).

In fact, though, you can make this more efficient, since either the lightest edge in *E1* or the lightest edge in *E2* must be used in some MST. Suppose that the lightest edge in *E1*, say *e'1*, is *not* used, and consider a cut agreeing with *e'1*. The MST must contain some *e ≠ e'1* connecting the cut. Clearly, if *e ∈ E1*, then *e'1* can be used instead of *e*. If *e ∈ E2*, though, and *e* can't be used, then *e* is lighter than *e'1*. In this case, though, repeating the argument for *E2*, yields that the lightest edge in *E2* can be part of the MST.

Consequently, only the lightest edge of *E1* along with any edge in *E2*, or the lightest edge in *E2* along with any edge in *E1* must be considered for the first two contractions mention above.

The complexity is *Θ(|E1 + E2| f(V, E1 + E2))*, where *f* is the complexity of the MST algorithm.